# database column update issue using python

Tags: python, oracle11g

I am trying to update a oracle db column using python dictionary.
I want to search the database column by dictionary key and replace by the dictionary value.I am trying to do the below but its not updating.

```
for key,value in my_dict.items():
    update_db_column(connection,key, value)

def update_db_column(connection,key,value):
     query="update table set column=:1 where column=:2"
     cur=con.cursor()
     cur.execute(query,(value,key))
     cur.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function `update_db_column` you take a variable named `connection`but then you refer to a variable named `con`. If these are meant to be the same thing they certainly need the same name.
Also by defining your function after the actual code you might be getting errors as well.
My guess is that your program is catching the errors without stopping the code and is just trying to move on, or `con` is referencing an earlier global variable. If you change your code to:

```
def update_db_column(connection,key,value):
     query="update table set column=:1 where column=:2"
     cur=connection.cursor()
     cur.execute(query,(value,key))
     cur.commit()

for key,value in my_dict.items():
    update_db_column(connection,key, value)
```

Does it fix it?

Comment: sorry ! the code is working. I think it was taking time to update.

Comment: Awesome, I hate it when that happens :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your script like this:

```
def update_db_column(connection,key,value):
    cur=connection.cursor()
    query="update table set " + key + " where " + key + "=:value"
    cur.prepare(query)
    cur.execute(None, {'value': value})
    cur.commit()

for key,value in my_dict.items():
    update_db_column(connection,key, value)
```

The few explanation of this change is [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/OOW11/python_db/python_db.htm), at **Using Bind Variables** section.